# DataGrid Updating for Added Rows but not for Added Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

I have an MVVM app with a data bound `DataGrid` bound to `Resources<ResourceViewModel>`. I add an additonal resource/row to the resource data shown in the `DataGrid` via

```
private void OnResourceAddedToCollection(object sender, ResourceCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = new ResourceViewModel(e.NewResource);
    Resources.Add(viewModel);
}
```

This works. However, I take exactly the same approach and attempt to add columns to the `DataGrid` via

```
private void OnResourceCultureCollectionChanged(object sender, 
    ResourceCulturesCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Resources.Clear();
    foreach (var rvm in e.NewResourceCollection.Select(r => new ResourceViewModel(r)).ToList())
        Resources.Add(rvm);
}
```

where the event arguments hold the updated underlying `Resource`s. Now I have checked the data and it is right - the columns are being added, but the `DataGrid` is not showing the new columns. **What am i doing wrong?**

Comment: I do not know, it will help or not, but try to set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`.

Comment: I can't, I am using a special binding to the grid which means I have to create the columns 'manually'. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Killercam, this just occurred to me, have you tried in your `OnResourceCultureCollectionChanged` to set Resources to null, then create a new list, then `Add(rvm)`? Wondering if that would reset the ItemSource and force datagrid to repaint. I doubt, but worth a try...

Comment: It doesn't. I have recently found this link http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection it is well worth a read and explains why this cannot happen...

Answer (score 1):

When adding columns you need to repaint the datagrid, reset your `DataGrid.ItemSource` should do it.

VIEW:

```
public SomeView(IViewModel vm)
{
    ViewModel = vm;
    DataContext = ViewModel;

    InitializeComponent();

    ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "IsResetingColumns":
                if (!ViewModel.IsResetingColumns)
                {
                    dataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
                    dataGrid.ItemsSource = ViewModel.Resources;
                }
                break;
            }
        };
    }
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isResetingColumns;

    public bool IsResetingColumns
    {
        get
        {
            return _isResetingColumns;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isResetingColumns == value)
                return;
            _isResetingColumns = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsResetingColumns");
        }
    }

    private void OnResourceCultureCollectionChanged(object sender,
                                                    ResourceCulturesCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //VIEWMODEL IS SETTING THIS TO TRUE BEFORE RESETTING `RESOURCES`
        IsResetingColumns = true;

        Resources.Clear();
        foreach (var rvm in e.NewResourceCollection.Select(r => new ResourceViewModel(r)).ToList())
            Resources.Add(rvm);

        //VIEW'S LISTENING TO THIS PROPERTY CHANGED (naming could be better, or an event ,but the gist is there)
        IsResetingColumns = false;
    }
```

Comment: No, I can't do this. This is an MVVM application - I cannot access the `DataGrid` directly (although I desperately want to!). Thanks for your help.

Comment: then why not add an event in ViewModel, then listen to that event on the View and update the `View.DataGrid.ItemsSource` then?

Comment: Because it would break the MVVM pattern!

Comment: Sorry don't mean to turn this into a forum, but how does it break MVVM? The ViewModel is free to signal about it's state, though properties or events. The View is injected with the ViewModel the same way, and listens to what is happening in the ViewModel and reacts appropriately. In this case, it knows that the change is drastic enough for it to having to rebind it's datagrid. In any case, hope you find the solution that you feel is more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. The ViewModel should not access any View components directly. It breaks MVVM in the case that I decide to switch my `DataGrid` for a `ListView` or a custom `DataGrid`. I know this is probably deemed pedantic, but I want to stick to MVVM strictly here. Moreover, it is not clear how I would access the `DataGrid` instance from the ViewModel directly. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: Oh, I agree with you absolutely, View should be `passive`. What I am trying to say is that the ViewModel that has the property `Resources` should have a property or event that it can set whenever it manipulates its `Resources` property. It obviously does it using two different approaches. So whenever, it adds columns, it can set an event or a property `ColumnsAreReset` so whoever binds to that ViewModel can react. Cheers.

Comment: Have you any idea on how to do this. I have an EventHandler that firs when the columns are changed so I can do what you suggest in there. However, I am still unsure how to bind this update process to the View.

Comment: I have updated the post with MVVM in mind, note that the view is passive, and VM just signals a big (column) change. I chose a property instead of the event, to show that either one would work...

Comment: Thanks very much for your time here, it is really appreciated. The only reservation with the above is that I have resigned to the fact that I want to be a MVVM angle, that is to keep the View totally clear of all activity - this might be a 'bridge too far'...